# Cast Sender running on Android Chrome or Firefox

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

Is there any way to build a pure JS/HTML5 Chromecast Sender implementation that runs in Chrome or Firefox on Android.

The Chromecast Chrome extension doesn't run on Android Chrome, so the only solution I can think of is to launch the Receiver via the desktop Chrome extension, then use WebRTC and webkitRTCPeerConnection to send messages between the Chromecast Receiver and a different Android Sender.

Both Android Chrome & Firefox support the data channels so at least once launched that might be a viable way to control the receiver. I wonder if anyone has any better ideas, or a way to get the Chromecast Chrome extension onto Android?

(Btw. I am aware that DIAL SDP uses UDP != WebRTC RTCDataChannels)

Comment: It looks like the Presentation API will get us there eventually. Right now on my android chrome I can start a cast session, but not do anything with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, currently there is no such solution on an Android device in pure JS/HTML5 in Android Chrome (nor Firefox for that matter).