# Launching Chromecast from WebRTC

Tags: webrtc, chromecast, google-cast

As indicated in an original question: [Cast Sender running on Android Chrome or Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467056/cast-sender-running-on-android-chrome-or-firefox)

Is there a way to launch Chromecast via WebRTC?

I have no doubt that when launched CC will be as big as the original iPhone, and the only thing preventing full HTML5 functionality is using the DIAL protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already know this isn't possible, @ali-naddaf could you enter this as a feature request by any chance please?

WebRTC is working great on our dev CC devices, the only thorn is having to use the Chrome extension to launch it before using WebRTC and WebSockets to take over.  Avoiding DIAL for launching pure web apps would be a real killer deal IMO.

BTW, I haven't been able to find a formal way to make feature requests so this Q/A mechanism was my approach.

Comment: You can post your feature requests to chromecast-updates@google.com